# как сделать проверку соответствия списка

Tags: java

как можно создать список по типу массива, в котором будут хранится данные и часть кода:

```
lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    String[] str2 = lineFromFile.split(Bosses + " " + "был повержен за "); 
                    if (str2.length > 1) { 
                        str2 = str2[1].split(" ");
                        int time = Integer.parseInt(str2[0]);
                        System.out.println(+time);
```

Будет сверять данные такого списка (под названием "Bosses")

```
String ZOMBIE_BOSS = Zombie; 
        String SLIME_BOSS = Slime;
        String SPIDER_BOSS = Spider;
        String COW_BOSS = Cow;
        String YETI_BOSS = Yeti;
        String LEVIK_BOSS = Levik;
        String FISH_BOSS = Fish;
        String GHAST_BOSS = Ghast;
```

например в Logs.txt написанно будет
[12:25:23] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Королевский зомби был повержен за 43 секунд! Нападавшие получили ценные сокровища!
Учитывая что есть переменные

```
String Zombie = "Королевский зомби";
    String Slime = "Сточный слизень";
    String Spider = "Матка";
    String Cow = "Коровка из Коровёнки";
    String Yeti = "Йети";
    String Levik = "Левиафан";
    String Fish = "Хранитель подводного мира";
    String Ghast = "Небесный владыка";
```

код должен был подобрать из этого списка переменную - String Zombie = "Королевский зомби";

и с переменными:

```
int time = Integer.parseInt(str2[0]);
                    int min = 60;
```

подставить формулу и вывести её на экран:

```
System.out.println(+time + 10 * min);
```

я не знаю как ещё это объяснить, надеюсь максимально понятно, короче говоря, цель работы - чекер для игры

Весь "проблемный" код для данного чекера

```
package Boss;
import java.io.*;
public class MathMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        String Zombie = "Королевский зомби";
        String Slime = "Сточный слизень";
        String Spider = "Матка";
        String Cow = "Коровка из Коровёнки";
        String Yeti = "Йети";
        String Levik = "Левиафан";
        String Fish = "Хранитель подводного мира";
        String Ghast = "Небесный владыка";
        
        String ZOMBIE_BOSS = Zombie; 
        String SLIME_BOSS = Slime;
        String SPIDER_BOSS = Spider;
        String COW_BOSS = Cow;
        String YETI_BOSS = Yeti;
        String LEVIK_BOSS = Levik;
        String FISH_BOSS = Fish;
        String GHAST_BOSS = Ghast;
            {   
                
                    
                
                String[] Bosses = new String[] {ZOMBIE_BOSS, SLIME_BOSS, SPIDER_BOSS, COW_BOSS, YETI_BOSS, LEVIK_BOSS, FISH_BOSS, GHAST_BOSS};
                
    
        String lineFromFile;
        String s = File.separator;
        String path = s+ "Users" +s+ "Арслан" +s+ "eclipse-workspace" +s+ "BossCheck" +s+ "src" +s+ "Boss" +s+ "Logs.txt";
    
        try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader
                (new FileInputStream(path), "Windows-1251")) { 
            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
                while (bufferedReader.ready()) {

                    lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    String[] str2 = lineFromFile.split(Bosses + " " + "был повержен за "); 
                    if (str2.length > 1) { 
                        str2 = str2[1].split(" ");
                        int time = Integer.parseInt(str2[0]);
                        int min = 60;
                        System.out.println(+time + 10 * min);
                    }

                }
           

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();{
                
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
}
```

что находится в папке logs.txt - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2diAO.jpg,
а так-же сама ошибка в консоли при выполнении данного кода:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 44
[Ljava.lang.String;@279f2327 был повержен за
^
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:2027)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2696)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2138)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2068)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1782)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:1429)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1069)
at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:2360)
at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:2407)
at Boss.MathMethod.main(MathMethod.java:40)

Comment: а вы когда-то слышали про коллекции Map ?

Comment: @Дмитрий нет, не слышал, вообще я начинающий java программист со средними знаниями алгебраических функций, определений и навыков английского языка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.*;
public class MathMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        String Zombie = "Королевский зомби";
        String Slime = "Сточный слизень";
        String Spider = "Матка";
        String Cow = "Коровка из Коровёнки";
        String Yeti = "Йети";
        String Levik = "Левиафан";
        String Fish = "Хранитель подводного мира";
        String Ghast = "Небесный владыка";

        String ZOMBIE_BOSS = Zombie;
        String SLIME_BOSS = Slime;
        String SPIDER_BOSS = Spider;
        String COW_BOSS = Cow;
        String YETI_BOSS = Yeti;
        String LEVIK_BOSS = Levik;
        String FISH_BOSS = Fish;
        String GHAST_BOSS = Ghast;
        {
            String[] Bosses = new String[] {ZOMBIE_BOSS, SLIME_BOSS, SPIDER_BOSS, COW_BOSS, YETI_BOSS, LEVIK_BOSS, FISH_BOSS, GHAST_BOSS};

            String lineFromFile;
            String s = File.separator;
            String path = s+ "Users" +s+ "Арслан" +s+ "eclipse-workspace" +s+ "BossCheck" +s+ "src" +s+ "Boss" +s+ "Logs.txt";

            try (InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader
                    (new FileInputStream(path), "Windows-1251")) {
                try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {
                    while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
                        lineFromFile = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        int bossIndex = -1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < Bosses.length; i++) {
                            if (lineFromFile.contains(Bosses[i])) {
                                bossIndex = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (bossIndex != -1) {
                            String[] str2 = lineFromFile.split(Bosses[bossIndex] + " " + "был повержен за ");
                            if (str2.length > 1) {
                                str2 = str2[1].split(" ");
                                int time = Integer.parseInt(str2[0]);
                                int min = 60;
                                System.out.println(+time + 10 * min);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();{
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: премного благодарю вас!

Comment: Для любителей стримов - `String finalLineFromFile = lineFromFile;
                        int bossIndex = IntStream.range(0, Bosses.length).filter(idx -> finalLineFromFile.contains(Bosses[idx])).findFirst().orElse(-1);`